# jQueryUI .extend woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to fix [this](http://jsbin.com/aqowa/edit#javascript,html) code for jQueryUI 1.8.5 and jQuery 1.5.1 and am out of luck with such advanced stuff, can anyone lend a hand?

The problem is with the code below:

```
$.extend($.ui.boxer, {
    defaults: $.extend({}, $.ui.mouse.defaults, {
        appendTo: 'body',
        distance: 0
    })
});
```

It doesn't initialize options with appendTo and distance values for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I haven't worked with jQuery UI before, I took a stab at this one for the night. It appears that you have two problems with the code you showed in jsfiddle. The first is that in UI 1.8, you no longer have to do extend when creating a widget,

```
$.widget("ui.boxer", $.ui.mouse, {
    ...
});
```

Switching to this new style of declaring a widget, the error for `this._mouseInit()` goes away. This was needed to be done before we can address the question you had, which was why defaults did not work. In this commit https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/90fb45dffafc2e891b1ebca948ad33e6b94de112, `ui.mouse.defaults` was replaced with `options`. Since `options` is part of the widget, you now have to extend the prototype,

```
$.extend($.ui.boxer.prototype, {
    options: $.extend({}, $.ui.mouse.prototype.options, {
        appendTo: 'body',
        distance: 0
    })
});
```

These changes resulted in something that works ( http://jsfiddle.net/wqvJG/1/ ). BTW, what this code does is awesome :).

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a go when I get back!

Answer (score 0):

That part seems to be working (I debugged it and made sure the appendTo is being said as expected.)  There was a warning about the tmp variable being used twice so I fixed that.  With that change, the demo seems to be working as I would think it should.  Is there anything wrong with it:

http://jsbin.com/aqowa/150/edit#javascript,html

Comment: It works because it uses jQuery 1.3.2 and jQueryUI 1.7.2, not 1.5.1 and 1.8.5. I am having problems fixing it for last two.

Comment: i see, maybe post a fiddle with it breaking so we can all debug it.  But my suggestion is just debug it and step into that function.  The ui.defaults probably just looks different in 1.8.x

Comment: that just seems like it has a problem on this line: `this._mouseInit();` which makes sense because _mouseInit isn't declared.